# Can Raspberry Pi 3 do 4K Video?

Tags: hdmi, video, pi-3

It looks like the Raspberry Pi 3 may be powerful enough to output 4K video, but I haven't seen anything about it anywhere.

Does anyone know if the Raspberry Pi 3 can output video over HDMI at 4K resolution? If so, is it 30Hz or 60Hz?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The best information I can find suggests that it's possible to output 4K resolutions, but at fairly miserable frame rates. The Pi 3 has the same GPU as the Pi 2, so the information should still be valid:

Source: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=79330

> I have managed to get 3840 x 2160 (4k x 2k) at 15Hz on a Seiki E50UY04
>   working under two distributions on the Raspberry Pi... (Latest
>   Wheezy/Openelec). The television shows it is receiving this resolution
>   and hertz level, and it looks very crisp.
>
> This is my config.txt for wheezy:
>
> ```
> # uncomment if you get no picture on HDMI for a default "safe" mode
> #hdmi_safe=1
>
> # uncomment this if your display has a black border of unused pixels visible
> # and your display can output without overscan
> disable_overscan=1
>
> # uncomment the following to adjust overscan. Use positive numbers if console
> # goes off screen, and negative if there is too much border
> overscan_left=-150
> overscan_right=-150
> #overscan_top=16
> #overscan_bottom=16
>
> # uncomment to force a console size. By default it will be display's size minus
> # overscan.
> #framebuffer_width=3840
> #framebuffer_height=2160
>
> # uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output
> #hdmi_force_hotplug=1
>
> # uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
> hdmi_group=2
> hdmi_mode=87
>
> # uncomment to force a HDMI mode rather than DVI. This can make audio work in
> # DMT (computer monitor) modes
> #hdmi_drive=2
>
> # uncomment to increase signal to HDMI, if you have interference, blanking, or
> # no display
> #config_hdmi_boost=4
>
> # uncomment for composite PAL
> #sdtv_mode=2
>
> #uncomment to overclock the arm. 700 MHz is the default.
> #arm_freq=800
>
> # for more options see http://elinux.org/RPi_config.txt
> hdmi_ignore_edid=0xa5000080
> hdmi_cvt 3840 2160 15
> ```

Comment: It does run the same gpu but at 400 instead of 250mhz

Comment: True. I've yet to see any analysis on what performance impact that might have on 4K frame rates.

Comment: The 400 vs 250mhz won't affect what HDMI can scan out.  HDMI's clocks are independent and also derive from elsewhere in the clock tree.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will be able to play but the frame rate should be very less else choppyness will be there or it might stuck at a frame as well.

Answer (score -4):

Try Chromecast 4k, you can stream from the RPi to Chromecast.

Comment: This isn't a very complete answer. Is the RPi cable of processing/transmitting that level of bandwidth? Is there a particular service needed to do so?