# Does Kodi not support ultra HD 4k videos?

Tags: pi-3, kodi

Yesterday night I installed Kodi the latest version on my raspbian OS, which is set to autostart as soon as pi boots, After adding 4k Video folder, I can browse through, play but I only hear audio no video for 4k videos, although I am able to play other videos.

The video I tried is Earth from ISS available on youtube as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Raspberry Pi 3 do 4K Video?](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/44089/can-raspberry-pi-3-do-4k-video)