# 2560x1080 how many Hz?

Tags: video

Periodically I’m tempted by the ultra wide monitors on the market.
If I buy one, it’ll be the 29” LG but my question is can the new pi 3b+ do 60 Hz at 2560x1080?

Comment: The Pi 3B+ apparently has HDMI 1.4, [which I think means it will support it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hdmi#Version_comparison), *without being able to check* though from the looks [4K (video) works](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/44089/can-raspberry-pi-3-do-4k-video). however it still has a similar GPU to previous versions so I'm not sure video etc will be able to run a native or higher resolution AND frequency.

Comment: No Raspberry Pi will play encoded video at reasonable framerates for resolutions greater than 1080i. I can't prove this for unencoded video, but the sheer bitrate should overwhelm any Pi easily, since I/O capacity will, is and always has been very limited on this platform.

Comment: Resolution of 2560x1440 is common.  Did you really mean 2560x1080?

Answer (score 0):

All Pi models have the same Video Core, so the Pi3B+ is no different to earlier models in this respect.

There are some limitations in the modes which can be supported due to the pixel clock limit. See
https://elinux.org/RPiconfig#Video

I suspect you are out of luck; even though the rate may be supported there seems to be no wide screen mode - it is possible to create custom modes. I have never seen a screen with a 64:27 ratio!

Comment: 2560x1080@50Hz is within the pixel clock limit.

Answer (score -2):

You can try this. 
with support for 2560x1080 resolution on LG25UM65 display. [2560x1080](https://gist.github.com/edupsousa/0bcf4652c62a5e1ce218)

Comment: "You can try this" is the only part of this answer I could parse.

Comment: I think you should add the config.txt to your answer and explain what it does. And remove the random, irrelevant values